# How to delete a pointer array full of class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory, delete-operator

I am working through some university tutorials and I have to delete this array I have made with pointers and I should see the deconstructors for each object in the array called as I delete it. Here is the code. (Csprite is the base class, CpowerPill, Cghost and Cpacman are derived classes)

```
    Csprite * psprites[3]; 

psprites[0]=new CpowerPill;
psprites[1]=new Cghost;
psprites[2]=new Cpacman;

delete psprites[0,1,2];


    cin >> endPro;
```

All I get when I run this a single deconstructor call from the base class when I should get 3 different deconstructors all from the respective derived classes. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm assuming that your code compiles; i.e. `Csprite` is the base class]

Since you've used `new` separately on each element, you need to use `delete` separately on each element:

```
delete psprites[0];
delete psprites[1];
delete psprites[2];
```

The comma notation that you've used in `delete psprites[0, 1, 2];` doesn't do what you think it does. `0, 1, 2` is just an expression with value 2, so all you're doing is deleting the final element.

As the array `psprites` is stack-allocated, you don't need to delete that. In fact, to do so would be *undefined behaviour*.

**One more thing**, you need to ensure that `Csprite` has a virtual destructor, or you'll leak memory. You can do that by writing `virtual ~Csprite(){}` in its class declaration.

Comment: could you show me how to make my Sprite destructor virtual please?

Comment: Added. But do make sure you understand it ;-)

Comment: I am just researching it now :)

Comment: I read up on it and your help fixed it, thanks a lot, you've really helped me out :)

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `[0,1,2]` doesn't do what you want, because the comma-operator simply returns it's last argument. You have to call delete on each element:

```
delete psprites[0]
delete psprites[1]
delete psprites[2]
```

This is typically done in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `delete` each element. You could do that manually:

```
delete psprites[0];
delete psprites[1];
delete psprites[2];
```

Or you could iterate through them with a loop.

The reason your current code doesn't work is because there's no such syntax as `[0,1,2]` for accessing multiple elements in a loop. The use of `,` is the comma operator, which has the value of its right operand. So what you've done is equivalent to `delete psprites[2];`. This is why you only get one destructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
 for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
          delete psprites[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        virtual ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl; }
    };

    struct B : A
    {
        ~B() { std::cout << "B::~B()" << std::endl; }
    };

    struct C : A
    {
        ~C() { std::cout << "C::~C()" << std::endl; }
    };

    struct D : A
    {
        ~D() { std::cout << "D::~D()" << std::endl; }
    };

    A * a[] = { new A, new B, new C, new D };

    std::for_each( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::default_delete<A>() );
}
```

As for your code then this statement `delete psprites[0,1,2];`is invalid. Inside the square brackets there is an expression with the comma operator. So this statement is equivalent to

```
delete psprites[2];
```